# ASP CORE dynamically update viewbag date headers

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, parameter-passing, viewbag

Hello I am brand new to asp core and have been tasked to make a diary application. I am having issues having the date headers of the table changing when clicking the previous week button.. It should show previous and next weeks dates when the buttons are pressed. Apologies in advance if this is a really stupid question or if I am going about doing it completely wrong. It works for getting the currents weeks dates whenever the page loads but can't get it flicking between weeks.

If theres anymore info required let me know.. Thanks :)

```
index.cshtml
<input type="submit" method="index" value="Previous Week" class="btn btn-light" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Appointment",new {mon = ViewBag.monday, tues = ViewBag.tuesday, wed = ViewBag.wednesday, thurs = ViewBag.Thursday, fri = ViewBag.friday, sat = ViewBag.saturday,sun = ViewBag.sunday})'"/>

<td width="87" align="center" <font color="#0000A0" size="1">Monday <br /> @ViewBag.monday </font></td>
            <td width="87" align="center" <font color="#0000A0" size="1">Tuesday<br>@ViewBag.tuesday</font></td>
```

```
AppointmentController
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            ViewBag.tuesday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            ViewBag.wednesday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            ViewBag.thursday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            ViewBag.friday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Friday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            ViewBag.saturday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            ViewBag.sunday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday + 7).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(DateTime mon, DateTime tues, DateTime wed, DateTime thurs, DateTime fri, DateTime Sat, DateTime sun)
        {
            //previous week
            ViewBag.Monday = mon.AddDays(-7);
            ViewBag.tuesday = tues.AddDays(-7);
            ViewBag.wednesday = wed.AddDays(-7);
            ViewBag.thursday = thurs.AddDays(-7);
            ViewBag.friday = fri.AddDays(-7);
            ViewBag.saturday = Sat.AddDays(-7);
            ViewBag.sunday = sun.AddDays(-7);
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track. But you could have a method for going back and one for going forward, so you have two links: one for forward and one back. Then in those methods you set the dates based on how many times you go backward -=1 each time

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this problem within a single action but i think ill space it out separate like Johan as said.. Ill post my current solution below incase it helps anyone in the future!

```
<input type="submit" method="index" value="Previous Week" class="btn btn-light" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Appointment",new {state = 1,mon = ViewBag.monday, tues = ViewBag.tuesday,
                                                                                                          wed = ViewBag.wednesday, thurs = ViewBag.Thursday, fri = ViewBag.friday, sat = ViewBag.saturday,
                                                                                                          sun = ViewBag.sunday})'"/>

                <input type="submit" value="Current Week" class="btn btn-light" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Appointment",new {state = 0,mon = ViewBag.monday, tues = ViewBag.tuesday,
                                                                                                          wed = ViewBag.wednesday, thurs = ViewBag.Thursday, fri = ViewBag.friday, sat = ViewBag.saturday,
                                                                                                          sun = ViewBag.sunday})'"/>

                <input type="submit" value="Next Week" class="btn btn-light" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Appointment",new {state = 2,mon = ViewBag.monday, tues = ViewBag.tuesday,
                                                                                                          wed = ViewBag.wednesday, thurs = ViewBag.Thursday, fri = ViewBag.friday, sat = ViewBag.saturday,
                                                                                                          sun = ViewBag.sunday})'"/>
```

```
public IActionResult Index(int state, string mon, string tues, string wed, string thurs, string fri, string Sat, string sun)
        {
            //var mon
            if (state <= 0)
            {
                ViewBag.monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.tuesday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.wednesday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.thursday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.friday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Friday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.saturday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.sunday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday + 7).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                return View();
            }
            else if(state == 1){
                var pmon = Convert.ToDateTime(mon).AddDays(-7);
                var ptues = Convert.ToDateTime(tues).AddDays(-7);
                var pwed = Convert.ToDateTime(wed).AddDays(-7);
                var pthur = Convert.ToDateTime(thurs).AddDays(-7);
                var pfri = Convert.ToDateTime(fri).AddDays(-7);
                var psat = Convert.ToDateTime(Sat).AddDays(-7);
                var psun = Convert.ToDateTime(sun).AddDays(-7);
                ViewBag.Monday = pmon.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
                ViewBag.tuesday = ptues.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.wednesday = pwed.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.thursday = pthur.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.friday = pfri.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.saturday = psat.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.sunday = psun.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                return View();
            }
            else if (state == 2)
            {
                var pmon = Convert.ToDateTime(mon).AddDays(7);
                var ptues = Convert.ToDateTime(tues).AddDays(7);
                var pwed = Convert.ToDateTime(wed).AddDays(7);
                var pthur = Convert.ToDateTime(thurs).AddDays(7);
                var pfri = Convert.ToDateTime(fri).AddDays(7);
                var psat = Convert.ToDateTime(Sat).AddDays(7);
                var psun = Convert.ToDateTime(sun).AddDays(7);
                ViewBag.Monday = pmon.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.tuesday = ptues.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.wednesday = pwed.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.thursday = pthur.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.friday = pfri.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.saturday = psat.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ViewBag.sunday = psun.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
```